# Test fastcgi daemon from Python

Tags: python, fastcgi

I have a dodgy PHP server that locks up a few times a day. The processes stay alive but nginx kicks off a gateway timeout. I've spent too long trying to fix it I just need it to work.

So I want to script something that runs twice a minute (I can handle that bit) that connects to the php-fpm server via socketed fastcgi and get a status, or just say "hello". It doesn't need to do anything but attempt to connect.

If it can't, I'll have it forcibly restart PHP, but again, I can do that bit.

So how do I connect to a FastCGI socket in a way that will let me know it's alive, from Python, without disturbing connections from nginx.